# error in paypal library Paypal_Lib.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal-ipn

When I have used `Paypal_lib.php` in codeigniter, below errors are generated.
so please provide alternation library of paypal for paypal ipn. I have followed this

> http://nithinkvarrier.in/coding/codeigniter/codeigniter-paypal-integration/

tutorial for integrate paypal ipn with codeigniter.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Function eregi() is deprecated

Filename: libraries/paypal_lib.php

Line Number: 208


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Filename: libraries/paypal_lib.php

Line Number: 243


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/paypal_lib.php

Line Number: 244


     A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Warning

    Message: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/paypal_lib.php

Line Number: 246
```

Comment: That article is almost four years old – so no wonder it is outdated. Go look for something more current. There is an official PayPal PHP SDK in GitHub, https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK – I suggest you try using that one.

Comment: the last ive found on github https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter but never tried

Comment: Also feel free to google error message (i.e. "Function eregi() is deprecated"). First (or random) link would give you article with neat solution. Also, listen to two comments above - they are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by this code

```
 if (preg_match( "~VERIFIED~i", $this->ipn_response))
    {
        // Valid IPN transaction.
        $this->log_ipn_results(true);
        return true;         
    }
```

instead of this code

```
   if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response))
    {
        // Valid IPN transaction.
        $this->log_ipn_results(true);
        return true;         
    }
```